# I need Android With API 23

Tags: android

I cant Find Android With API 23 as well as System Image and Source With Direct Link , I need Android With API 23 and All things is Important for Android Programming With API 23

Comment: so let's go get them!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at my answer here:
[Downgrading from API 24 to API 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660103/downgrading-from-api-24-to-api-23/38660261#38660261)

You only need to change the `minSdkVersion` in `build.gradle(Module app) file`to 23.