# Downgrading from API 24 to API 23

Tags: android, android-studio, android-api-levels

I cant drag and drop items either on `activity_main.xml` file or `content_main.xml` file. From my research, I learned that I have to downgrade from android API 24 to android API 23, but when I click on API 24 image to downgrade I can't find API 23.

[image]

Comment: You have to install other SDK. Go to SDK Manager and install lower versions of sdk, then restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the image and download API 23, then restart Android Studio and you will see API 23 too there.

[image]

You will see this window, then start the download:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing `rendering API level` to `application API level`. You see, the icon above will render according to the API level you chose. That makes seance because some APIs have different overall design.

If you want to `downgrade the application API` you can change in the manifest (if you are using eclipse) OR change in the gradle settings(if you are using Android Studio) like so:

In the build.gradle(Module app):

```
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.shlomi.alarm"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Insert your API level in `minSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to your res directory through your windows explorer there you may find folders like 1)drawable 2)drawable-v24 3)layouts and so on.....
cut all the content from drawable-v24 and paste it into drawable folder.
This solution worked for me.
cheers.